# Users making edits by putting displaystyle or other inappropriate scaling in the title

Tags: discussion, support, editing, suggested-edits, titles

I have noticed there are a few users who consistently use inappropriate scaling in their post titles and edits they make, and not all of these users are new. I have edited those posts previously, and added comments like removed display style from title since it is unnecessary in a title, but they still do this.

Additionally, I have read [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles) and [Why no use displaystyle in titles?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/why-no-use-displaystyle-in-titles) so it appears that the consensus is not to do this.

Should I continue to correct these edits or just let it go?

Comment: Have you tried pinging them? It works (*sometimes*)!

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ I leave comments to them so if they check their post or see the one they just edited they should read the message.

Comment: There's possibility that they aren't notified. Why not comment on posts by that specific user or pinging them in chat.

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ I will give it a try in my next encounter to see how it is accepted by said user or users.

Comment: Flagging such a post will alert the moderators.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I think flagging might be overkill. Need to hear from a mod on that option though.

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ Why not just ping the editor on the post they edited?

Comment: @quid what I am trying out is pinging the person with the following message to see how it is recieved: In titles, left, right, and displaystyle are discouraged. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles for more information.

Comment: @quid Were you notified for [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085150/residue-of-fracz3z-1z-2z-3-at-z-infty/1085169#comment2211284_1085169) one?

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ Sure. While editors are not proposed as ping-targets, they can be ping-ed. // dustin: I think this is fine.

Comment: @quid one issue is if they have a name with nonstandard symbols so those people won't be pingable without the auto suggestions.

Comment: I am not sure what you refer to. If  it is just about the typing, you could copy-paste the name. (Also the first three letters suffice, if there is not collision, which avoids the issue sometimes.)

Comment: @quid Thanks I didn't know about that!

Comment: @quid what I mean is look at integrators name. I can only type the first letter I. With names that have nonstandard symbols, how would they get pinged without autocomplete?

Comment: @dustin: You can copy and paste, e.g.,  Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ.

Comment: Yes I understood that. My proposal for these rare cases is to copy-paste the username. Wouldn't this work? (There might still be an issue if you have not even correct display of the special characters, but perhaps this is rare enough to ignore it or would also be something one could fix.)

Comment: @dustin Re "flagging might be overkill": It may be overkill if you do it before addressing the editor, we should assume that they're well-meaning and just don't know they shouldn't do that (if there's a history telling you it wouldn't be wise to address the editor yourself, things are/may be different). If addressing them in a comment doesn't lead to a change in behaviour, flagging becomes the necessary thing to do at some point. Whether that is after the first time telling them to stop, after the second, third ... should be judged on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I much rather see $\lim \limits_{x\to a}$ than $\lim _{x\to a}$, so what if it takes up space on the front page?

Comment: @Gitgud check out the link post and you will see there is nothing against that.

Comment: @dustin I fail to realise the difference between \lim \limits and \displaystyle in the case of $\lim$.

Comment: @GitGud check out [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math) post on TeX. You will see there is a difference between display and limits.

Comment: I'm bumping this question, since I've been getting annoyed by people using `\displaystyle` or `\dfrac` in titles. I'm also imploring people who come across this to remove these whenever they come across it in a question's title.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As long as you have the energy to do so, please continue to correct such edits/titles.

Unless you have reason not to, assume the editors are well-meaning and just don't know that `\displaystyle` should generally not be used in titles, and address a comment to them - editors of a question can be `@`-pinged, although their username does not appear in the auto-complete list unless they commented on the post - asking them to stop adding it to titles. Linking to the meta posts about that issue in the comment is a good idea. If these requests don't lead to a change in behaviour, there comes the time to raise a flag describing the problem (if you happen to have a list of incidents handy to include in the flag message, that would be great; if not, the moderators will look for themselves).

---

A general remark about editing (not addressed at the OP of this question):

Whatever common mistake one fixes in posts, be that retagging wrongly tagged questions, fixing spelling mistakes, eliminating `\displaystyle` from titles or something else, please don't do that in rapid enough succession to flood the front page with such edits. Take your time - and look over the post whether there is more in need of improvement.

(It frequently happens that somebody compiles a list of posts with a specific mistake to fix and then edits them in quick succession, without improving anything else. That is suboptimal.)